# If user photo not present then display generic image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip

In my application I have the option for a user to upload an image for a profile picture through paperclip.

Want I want to do in the index.html.erb page is to display all users with their display pictures, and if they have not uploaded one then it should display a default picture.

Now I have tried coding it in but at the moment the users who have pictures have the displayed but those who don't get nothing.

I have the following code in my user model:

```
def user_photo
  (photo.url.present?) ? photo.url : '/images/guest.png'
end
```

and the following code in my index.html.erb

```
<% for user in @users %>
 .............
  <%= image_tag user.user_photo, :height => 50, :width => 50 %>
 ..............
 <% end %>
```

Any ideas on what my problem might be?

Thanks

Comment: What's the generated HTML like in the case of the guest? What does `img src` say? what happens if you point your browser to that URL? Have you tried accessing `guest.png` manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have something like this in your user model:

```
has_attached_file :photo, 
    :default_url => '/images/guest.jpeg',
    :styles => { 
      :large => "300x300>",
      :thumb => "100x100>",
      :tiny  => "32x32>"
    }
```

The :default_url option is used if there is no attached file for a model. If a user doesn’t have any uploaded photo you could use this option to set a default photo to show.

In the view:

```
<%= image_tag @user.photo.url(:thumb) %>
```

Read [Paperclip usage guide](http://jimneath.org/2008/04/17/paperclip-attaching-files-in-rails.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is view logic, I would put it in a helper instead of in the model. So in a relevant helper:

```
def user_photo(user)
  user.photo.url.present? ? image_tag user.user_photo : image_tag 'guest.png'
end
```

Then call that helper from the view. Of course you can add other parameters to image_tag for the dimensions and so on. This way you get the benefit of using the image_tag helpers consistently.